# Filling staggered groups of cells with ones or zeroes

Tags: excel

I want to fill the columns from 1 to n (say n=2000) with 1's in Excel. Is there anyway to program in excel to get this?

For example: 4 rows and 10000 columns. First 2000 columns have 1 in the first row, the next 2000 have 1 in the second row and so on.

```
1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

P.S: I need this for solving a multiclass classification problem.

Answer (score 2):

After setting up the parameters, a simple for/next loop with some maths for the offset per row should suffice.

```
Sub fill_cols()
    Dim r As Long, cs As Long, rs As Long, lc As Long

    rs = 4
    cs = 2000
    lc = 10000

    With ActiveSheet
        If lc > Columns.Count Then
            For r = 1 To rs
                .Cells(1, r).Resize(lc, 1) = 0
                .Cells(1, r).Offset((r - 1) * cs, 0).Resize(cs, 1) = 1
            Next r
        Else
            For r = 1 To rs
                .Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, lc) = 0
                .Cells(r, 1).Offset(0, (r - 1) * cs).Resize(1, cs) = 1
            Next r
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I've added a transposition of columns to rows and vise-versa if the requested column exceed the maximum columns in the worksheet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just started to learn VB programming, I wrote this code in the "view code" option. I want to know how to execute this. Apologies

Comment: You put it into a worksheet's code sheet named something like Book1 - Sheet1 (Code). You need to remove it and put it in a module code sheet. After removing it from the worksheet code sheet, use Insert ►Module and paste the above into the new pane titled something like Book1 - Module1 (Code). When pasted, use Alt+Q to return to your worksheet then Alt+F8 to open the macros dialog and Run the code.

Comment: Hi again, using similar logic(for loops), I tried executing the following code to get the same result, however i am getting run time error
<br>
Sub CycleThrough()
    Dim Counter As Long
    For Counter = 1 To 61879
        If Counter < 1931 Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Counter).Value = 1
        If Counter > 1930 Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Counter).Value = 0
    Next Counter
End Sub
<br>
When i tried to debug, it is highliting the second if? Can you please pooint out where the problem is occuring ?

Comment: i realize that excel does not permit more than 16,384 coloumns, may be thats why it is causing run-time error

Comment: Yes, you would have to use 61,879 rows × 4 columns and transpose the way you use it.

Comment: I've modified the sub to automatically transpose the columns to rows is the requested columns exceed the number of available columns.